# JS/JQuery/Arduino update div automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino

I've created an Arduino project that is currently hosting a local server that refreshes every 10 seconds (meta content).

The server at the moment simply prints one statement to the web client, 'low', 'medium' or 'high' depending on the state of the sensor.

I have attempted to create a pulsing circle using css/js to display the temperature (blue for low, orange for medium and red for high). What I'd like to do is get the circle to change colour depending on the state of the sensor automatically without the need for a meta content refresh or pressing enter.

So far I've been trying the following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Alert</title>
<!-- css -->
<style>
#phone {
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
}
.holder {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.circle {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #eb6d05;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 65px;
}
.ring {
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2.5s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: pulse 2.5s ease-out;
    animation: pulse 2.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
#holder .default .circle {
    background-color: #eb6d05;
}
#holder .default .ring {
        border-color: #eb6d05;

}
#holder .sync .circle {
    background-color: #57C1C1;
}
#holder .sync .ring {
        border-color: #57C1C1;

}
#holder .alert .circle {
    background-color: #E4332A;
}
#holder .alert .ring {
        border-color: #E4332A;

}

 @-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
 -moz-transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0.0;
}
 25% {
 -moz-transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0.1;
}
 50% {
 -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
 opacity: 0.3;
}
 75% {
 -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
 100% {
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 0.0;
}
}
 @-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
 0% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0.0;
}
 25% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0.1;
}
 50% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
 opacity: 0.3;
}
 75% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 0.0;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
<div id="holder">
  <div id="phone" class="default"><!--<img src="" border="0" height="564px">-->
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input name="" id="txt" type="text" value="">
</div>
<!-- Core JavaScript Files   --> <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notify() {
        var ct = $( "#txt" ).val();
        console.log(ct);

    if(ct == "a") {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("alert");
        console.log("1");
    }
    else if(ct == "b") {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("sync");
        console.log("2");
    }
    else {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("default");
        console.log("3");
    }
}
    $( "#txt" ).on( "change", notify );
    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

What's the best way to get the Arduino to print the state and the script to detect it and update it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Get the server answer with ajax by simply doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notify() {
        var ct = $( "#txt" ).val();
        console.log(ct);

    if(ct == "a") {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("alert");
        console.log("1");
    }
    else if(ct == "b") {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("sync");
        console.log("2");
    }
    else {
        $("#phone").removeClass();
        $("#phone").addClass("default");
        console.log("3");
    }
}
    $( "#txt" ).on( "change", notify );

$.ajax({
     url: 'serverurl',
     dataType: 'text'
}).done(function(data){
     $("#txt").val(data);
});
</script>
```